# Rookie can't locate connection string for DynamoDB in AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I can't believe I have to ask this but where is the connection string in AWS so that I can connect to my DynamoDB?  My code snippet below shows you want I need.  Looking at the "DynamoDB dashboard" page within AWS I can't see it.

The only thing that stands out is the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) value but I assume that's not the setting I need for my snippet of code below(?)

Many thanks,

**Configuration (snippet of code)**

```
module.exports = {
  db: 'mongodb://my_user:my_password@url:port/db',
  db_dev: 'mongodb://url:port/db',
};
```

- where do I get the "url" from in AWS?

**Update**

```
// Load the SDK and UUID
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({
  keyId: '...',
  accessKey: '...',
  region: '...'
});

// Create the DynamoDB service object
var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
var params = {
  TableName: 'customer',
  Item: {
    'email' : {S: 'test@test.com'}
  }
};

// Call DynamoDB to add the item to the table
ddb.putItem(params, function(err, data) {

  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } 
  else {
    console.log("Success", data);
  }

});
```

**Response**

```
 ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found

 message: 'Requested resource not found',
  code: 'ResourceNotFoundException',
  time: 2019-03-08T21:14:23.831Z,
  requestId: '...',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: ... }
```

**Second update**

I've tried the following code example but when I run "node myscript.js" it timeouts with the following error

[github link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/master/javascript/example_code/dynamodb/ddb_putitem.js)

**Error**

```
Error { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 1.1.1.1:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1083:14)
  message: 'connect ETIMEDOUT 1.1.1.1:443',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'NetworkingError',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '1.1.1.1',
  port: 443,
  region: 'REGION',
  hostname: 'dynamodb.region.amazonaws.com',
```

retryable: true,
  time: 2019-03-08T22:06:46.409Z }

Comment: Three things I can think to check. 1) Make sure the table is created 2) Make sure the region is correct 3) Make sure the user has the correct DynamoDB permissions in IAM. Any of these could result in your error message.

Comment: I just checked your code. You are using the literal 'REGION' for your region. This should be something like 'us-east-1', depending on which region your table is in.

Comment: If your intention was to use a variable, don't put it in quotes.

Comment: To get it working the keyid and accesskey placeholders above are just the string values rather than referencing a variable but I'm failing to get it working with this approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using the nodejs SDK? If so, you don't use a connections string, you create the client like this:

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

// Create the DynamoDB service object
var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
```

If you were using a local instance you would also do:

```
AWS.config.update({endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000'});
```

Comment: Ok, let me try it now.  Thanks (and yes, it's Node)

Comment: where do you specify username/ password etc..?

Comment: Lookup AWS credential chain. Basically, it you're running locally, either from a local file or your environment variables.

Comment: Have tried the following (see my update in the question) although without success